# Self-tracking entities extension methods

Tags: entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

When the context is generated i see there are some extension methods : AcceptChanges, MarkAsAdded, MarkAsDeleted, MarkAsModified.
When should i use these methods since they are available only on the service?

Answer (score 0):

They are available on the client as well - make sure you've included their namespace at the beginning of your file. If not, the intellisense will not offer a suggestion for it since these are extension methods.

Usually, you reference the same project on the client side, and you should have these methods as well. You use them when appropriate of course.